# Use of undefined constant makes - assumed 'makes'

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following `route` in my `laravel` project

```
 Route::get('/',[

   'uses' => 'MakeController@index'

  ]);
```

`Controller`

```
   class MakeController extends Controller{


    public function index(){

        $makes = MakeType::all();        
        return View::make('Index', $makes);
        // tried this
        //  return view('Index',compact('makes'));
    }
}
```

`index.blade.php`

```
<select>
       <option>Select Make</option>
             @foreach($makes as $make)

                 <option>{{$make->name}}</option>

             @endforeach
</select>
```

**Problem:**

The problem is when I try to load the `index` page, it shows me the following error

> Use of undefined constant makes - assumed 'makes' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: /customers/6/1/4/alle-voertuigen.nl/httpd.www/resources/views/Index.blade.php)

I've visit all the possible links, and tried different ways of doing it, but nothing is working with me.

This is what it is showing when I do `dd($makes)`, in `attributes` I have the `name` column

[image]
Please help me, thanks

Comment: This usually happens when you miss a `$` from a variable name. I suspect either the code shown isn't where the error is, or isn't what is actually there.

Comment: I believe it's `return View::make('Index', ['makes' => $makes]);`

Comment: Try `php artisan view:clear` and temporarily remove extra code except for the one you think is a problem and check.

Comment: I'm making changes to live site, not on `localhost` @Rahul

Comment: command-line exists everywhere. My tweaks shouldn't be affected by the environment I guess. What's the problem?

Comment: Where I can run `php aritsan view:clear` while I'm hosted files ?

Comment: `Undefined property: stdClass::$name (View: /customers/6/1/4/alle-voertuigen.nl/httpd.www/resources/views/Index.blade.php)`, this is problem @Rahul

Comment: the root folder of the project where your code is deployed.

Comment: I can't see any option @Rahul

Comment: why there is `Undefined property:stdClass ...` thing ? @Rahul

Comment: dd($makes) in your controller you will get it

Comment: that is returning an array @Rahul

Comment: update your question with that output

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot I added, the result of `dd($makes)`, @Rahul

Comment: Makes module doesn't have `makes` folder in views? index.blade.php you are trying to load?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you @Rahul

Comment: There are different modules, right? users, makes, logs, etc? and every module must be having its controller, model, and folder inside resources/views.

Comment: Yeah, you are talking about models , right ? @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` in your controller.

```
return View::make('Index')->with(compact('makes'));
```

Should work.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the response,  now it shows me this 

`Undefined property: stdClass::$name (View: /customers/6/1/4/alle-voertuigen.nl/httpd.www/resources/views/Index.blade.php)`

Although I've `name` column in my table

Comment: I made changes have a look now.

Comment: @Jonnix Your comment expired now. Please remove it and remove downvote too as I have updated my answer.

Comment: If you're just going to change the entire context of the answer, deleting and submitting a new one would have probably been more appropriate imo, but sure.

Comment: @Jonnix Thanks but the answer will be still visible to me even after deletion and extra data space will be consumed at SO if I delete and post new one. :D

Comment: @Rahul I honestly don't think SO care about an extra answer or an extra 1 million :P. But moving on.

Comment: @Rahul , it's not working dear, still the new error of `undefined property` I mentioned earlier

Comment: can you please update your question with `dd($makes); ` in a controller? just to make sure, that data exists.

Comment: You're talking about it from 2 different perspectives. Sure as developers we care that we store data efficiently in our code / DBs and with as little rubbish as possible. But deleting and adding answers as _users_ of a service where such actions are expected (and we assume said service will store relevant data as well as possible) is a separate thing. But now we've really got off track XD.

Answer (score -1):

If you use this way to return a view, you must use `with` to add parameters :

```
return View::make('Index')->with('makes', $makes);
```

I will advise to use the `view` helper, I don't know what version of Laravel you use :

```
return view('Index', ['makes' => $makes]);
```

Just only thing sure, it can't work if you don't pass variables as an array (with `compact` or `['myVariable' => $var]`)

Comment: already tried the `first` you've mentioned, but it gives me this 

`Undefined property: stdClass::$name (View: /customers/6/1/4/alle-voertuigen.nl/httpd.www/resources/views/Index.blade.php)`.
I've `name` column in my table,  why is this so ?

Comment: You are not clear about your errors and tries, hard to understand. `Undefined property` is clear enought ? you just don't have a `name` property, dump your variables, do your job

Comment: Yeah, I've `dd()` the data for one record , there is `name`, I can see that

Answer (score -2):

```
class MakeController extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        $makes = MakeType::all();        
        return View::make('index', $makes);
        // tried this
        //  return view('index',compact('makes'));
    }
}
```

its `index` not `Index`

Comment: Nope. If this was the issue, error would have been view not found.