# Undefined property: stdClass::$id inside View

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fetching `records` and sending it to a `view` in laravel, but when I try to show that data inside `view` through `@foreach` loop, it gives me

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id (View: F:\projexion\projexonproject\newlaravel\resources\views\Index.blade.php)

`controller`

```
class MakeController extends Controller
 {

    public function index(){

    $makes = MakeType::limit(5)->get();
    // dd($makes);  
    // die();

    return view('Index',compact('makes'));
 }
}
```

`@foreach` loop looks like this

```
@foreach($makes as $m)
   {{$m->id}}
@endforeach
```

[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672967/use-of-undefined-constant-makes-assumed-makes?noredirect=1#comment101794524_57672967), please have a look !

The following is the result of the data when I do `dd($makes)`
[image]

**Note**:  Either I do `{{$m->anycolumnName}}`, it gives me the `undefined property` thing.

Please help me because I'm have spent my previous whole day,trying to solve this , thanks.

Here is when I `dd($makes)` inside view

[image]

`Make Type Model`

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MakeType extends Model{
    public $table = 'qz7ov_expautos_make';

    public function makes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ModelType');
    }


}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198589/discussion-on-question-by-contributor-undefined-property-stdclassid-inside-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name and relationship name get mixed somehow in view. So use a different variable name.

```
public function index(){  
    $xyz = MakeType::limit(5)->get();
    return view('Index',compact('xyz'));
}
```